# i am making a password strength tester and currently am stuck in python

Tags: python, text, passwords

i am making a program that takes 10 passwords from a text document and checks the strength on each password based on a certain criteria( how long the password is,use of uppercase and lower case letters, numbers, and other characters)

my problem is i can't separate each individual password and add the points that each criteria is assigned.. thanks in advance for your help

these are the passwords that i am using ECOO()123abc9876, 123412345, ecoo2012, Bailey1234, Programmer, ContestT1mE, !23$5^7*(), (99876Ghg), StarWars, Samsung

```
    from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import Counter

with open("passwords.txt") as f:
    print( Counter(letter for line in f
                  for letter in line.lower()
                  if letter in ascii_lowercase))
```

Comment: Show us and add to the question the content of `passwords.txt` please.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that you are missing the fundamentals of both Python and the task at hand. This is way beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question; you need to actually start learning programming in general if you expect to solve this problem and understand the way problems like this are approached.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us your criteria for computing the strength of a given password, but this basic logic should get you through:

```
import string

def score(pw):
    length = len(pw)

    uppers = set(ascii_uppercase)
    upper = len([i for i in pw if i in uppers])

    lowers = set(ascii_lowercase)
    lower = len([i for i in pw if i in lowers])

    # and any other criteria

    return length + upper + lower  # and anything else


def main(infilepath):
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            pw = line.strip()
            print("The strength of", pw, "is", score(pw))
```

Comment: these are the passwords that i am using                         ECOO()123abc9876,
123412345,
ecoo2012,
Bailey1234,
Programmer,
ContestT1mE,
!23$5^7*(),
(99876Ghg),
StarWars,
Samsung